# JFrame keep the same window aspect ratio while resizing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am working on Linux Gnome.

I want to keep the window in a 16:9 ratio. If for example the width is scaled the code only modifies the height so the user input is not touched.

With this approach the window resizes itself further out than it should.
For example I scale the width a little bit and the height pops out much larger than it should.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
        panel.setBackground(new Color(89, 108, 171, 255));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        panel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
            {
                int targetWidth = frame.getSize().width;
                int targetHeight = frame.getSize().width * 9 / 16;

                if (targetHeight > frame.getSize().height)
                {
                    targetHeight = frame.getSize().height;
                    targetWidth = frame.getSize().height * 16 / 9;
                }

                frame.setSize(targetWidth, targetHeight);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest not changing the size of the frame. Instead change the preferred size of the component being displayed. That way the frame will lay it out. If you put it in a BorderLayout or a FlowLayout and set the preferred size. When the frame lays it out it should pad the remaining space. So you're window won't be the correct aspect ratio, but your component will.

Comment: Otherwise, your current technique might work, you would just need to improve the resizing condition/function.

Comment: I don’t think this can be done.  Java provides no way to be notified when a resize operation is *complete,* so you would be resizing the frame while the user’s resize is still in progress, creating all sorts of bizarre behavior.  A better idea is to call setResizable(false) and add options in the application that let the user choose from a known set of window sizes.  (I’m assuming it’s a game, since few other types of applications have a valid reason to specify an exact window size.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with.

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
    panel.setBackground(new Color(89, 108, 171, 255));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLocation(100, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.add(panel);
    frame.setContentPane(p2);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    p2.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
        {
            int fw = frame.getSize().width;
            int fh = frame.getSize().height;
            if( 16*fh > 9*fw ){
                panel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(fw, 9*fw/16) );
            } else{
                Dimension d = new Dimension(16*fh/9, fh);
                panel.setPreferredSize( d );
            }

            frame.validate();
        }
    });
```

This way, you're not changing a value the user is adjusting. (The size of the frame) You're responding to the change and making sure you're panel is still the correct size.

Comment: I thought of this, I too think this is the best solution for me